# Figures (jpg or pdf) and PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I'm writing a document that includes both a pdf file (using package graphicx) and some pstricks figures. When I compile using LateX+PdfTeX using --shell-escape, I am able to see the pdf file but not the pstricks figures. When I compile using LaTeX+TeX&Dvi, I am able to see the pstricks figures but not the pdf figures.

Any chance of having both together?

Working on TeXShop for mac.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Maybe the `auto-pst-pdf` package could help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! With `pdflatex`, you also must load `auto-pst-pdf` (*after* pstricks). These times, it didn't work for me, though. If it doesn't work for you either, compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: Thanks, I already loaded auto-pst-pdf, and it is not working. By the way, I don't know how to use xelatex in TeXShop

Comment: I don't have TeXshop, but I remember some friends of mine use, and there must be some Option submenu which lets you specify the default compiler. B.t.w., `auto-pst-pdf` works if  the compiler is launched with the  `-shell-escape` switch.

Comment: In TeXShop you can use from the menue (typesetting) xelatex.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers. The --shell-escape option is what I'm using under pdflatex, and it compiles the pdf figures but not the pstricks ones. If I use the LaTeX and DVI, that is not an option. I've tried xelatex, but it requires utf-8 instead inputenc and it's a mess with the spanish words.

Comment: @JavierPérez: For _all_ engines inputenc is not needed if you use UTF8. And, of course,  there should be no problem with spanisch words! Give an example what fails?